# Finding Shortest Distance From any point on $f(x)$ to $g(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Assume I have function $y=f(x)$ in 2D. For any point on that function, e.g. $(x, f(x))$ what would be an equation I could derive that determines the closest point $f(x)$ for any value $x$ to another function (call it $g(x)$).
My intuition was to find the smallest possible value for the distance between both points (seen as the radius of a circle) however after writing out each vector, I just got an expression with two variables that I could not differentiate with respect to one variable. I tried using multivariable calculus to find a gradient vector, but I only know how to do this for 3d - not 2d. Any help would be appreciated.

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} b}|\vec{s}|=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} b}\left[(a-b)^{2}+(f(a)-g(b))^{2}\right]
$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Formally, you can write one curve as $(x_1, f(x_1))$ and the other as $(x_2,g(x_2))$.  The distance between two points is then $d(x_1,x_2)=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(g(x_2)-f(x_1))^2}$  Now you can demand that $\frac {\partial d(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1}=\frac {\partial d(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2}=0$ which is equivalent to asking that the line segment from $(x_1, f(x_1))$ to $(x_2,g(x_2))$ hits each curve perpendicularly.  There is no guarantee that this calculation will be tractable.

Comment: Yes, however the line segment does not hit each curve perpendicularly for every point (this is only true when the derivatives are the same, which they are not always). The segments only hits one curve perpendicularly, and that would be curve f(x), as seen in the image above.

Comment: If it does not hit both curves perpendicularly you can slide the meeting point on the one not met perpendicularly in the direction the angle is acute and reduce the distance.  In your figure it looks like neither is perpendicular and you can slide both meeting points down and left to reduce the distance.  If the meet with the $(x,f(x))$ curve is perpendicular but the one with $(b,g(b)$ is not, you can slide $b$ down the curve to reduce the distance.

Comment: Yes but that would find the points at which the distance between two curves is the shortest - which is not exactly what I am trying to do. I am trying to find for any one point $(x1,f(x1))$ what is its closest point on $g(x)$. Therefore, no sliding of $(x1,f(x1))$ is allowed in this problem. Also as seen in the picture above, the distance is perpendicular to the tangent of the curve as the closest point.

Comment: Then you differentiate with respect to $x_2$ and set it to zero.  That forces the meeting on the second curve to be perpendicular.

Comment: So you are saying I find $\frac{∂d(x1,x2)}{∂x2}$ then equate it to zero? That would just give me the expression $2(x_{2}-x_{1})+2g'(x)(g(x_{2})-f(x_{1}))=0$. Even if this true, my original question was to isolate $x_{1}$ to equal an expression with only $x_{2}$. Not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: For a given $x_1$, finding the closest $x_2$ is exactly what you say.  The line between the points needs to be perpendicular to the $(x_2,g(x_2))$ curve.  Without knowing the form of $f,g$ no more can be said.  You should be looking to isolate $x_2$ as equal to some expression in $x_1$, not the other way around, because $x_1$ is given.